# validate_presence_of does not produce 'can't be blank' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I received this error from my rspec when using `validate_presence_of`:

```
Expected errors to include "can't be blank" when country_code is set to nil
```

This possible happened because of this line I wrote: `before_validation :autofill_country_code`
where it does the following:

```
def autofill_country_code
  unless self.country_code.present?
    country = GeoCache.geocode(self.city).country_code
    country_code = IsoCountryCodes.find(country).calling
    self.country_code = country_code.tr('+', '')
  end
end
```

The test passes if I remove this validation. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the functionality that you've described, your code is correct, but your test is wrong.  The country code *would* never be nil, so "validate_presence_of" will always fail.  You should write a test to make sure that the country_code is assigned before validation instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are assigning a country code `before_validation`, RSPEC will test the model with `country code` initially set to `nil` but actually before validation it is assigned, thus the validation is both non-reachable and redundant. The only way for this validation to produce an error is if your geocoding returned `nil`. The test will also pass if you remove the `before_validation` method.

Comment: That means I have to use `before_save` which was my initial choice. But that caused my other test to fail. I created a model where `country_code` is blank. `autofill_country_code` method was not running `before_save`.

Comment: Or you don't need to validate this field since you already assign it. Can you show me the other test?

Comment: To give a bit more context, I want that piece of code to run only if the user did not fill in the `country_code`. Since it is a separate issue, I have opened the follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836780/model-running-before-spec