# Model running before spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following spec file:

```
describe 'before_save autofill country code' do
  it "should autofill country code" do
    empty_country_code = nil
    @store = Factory.build(:store, :country_code => empty_country_code)
    expect{ @store.save }.to change { @store.country_code }.from(nil).to('1')
  end
end
```

The factory is defined like so:

```
Factory.define :store do |store|
  store.city "New York"
  store.country_code "81"
end
```

My model has the following lines:

```
before_save :autofill_country_code
```

where

```
def autofill_country_code
  unless self.country_code.present?
    country = GeoCache.geocode(self.city).country_code
    country_code = IsoCountryCodes.find(country).calling
    self.country_code = country_code.tr('+', '')
  end
end
```

To my understanding, when I run a spec file, it should run from the spec first. However, after prying the code for a while, I realized that the model is loading first. It filled `country_code` with `81` therefore failing to run `autofill_country_code`.

Afterwards, it goes to the spec file and sets `country_code` to `nil`. Thinking about it as I write this, the `expect` line of my spec could be wrong. I get an error stating:

```
result should have been changed to "1", but is now nil
```

Any ideas?